# Is it useful to create two concurrent queues in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am assuming that i am reading a well written code, since the developer is some twenty years old experienced guy, I have encountered a situation that he is using two concurrent queues for sending two different types of payload to the network, The network is a persistent TCP connection.

I know that Queues helps in dynamic thread management for us. So is there any case where it is advantage to create two concurrent queues, Even single can solve the situation, does it increase the performance, If so how? Thread management can be done by single queue itself, Isn't it?

Comment: Short answer: Yes.  Long answer: not for this forum.

Comment: @Avi can you show me the way to forum, thanks

Comment: All I meant is that SO is not the forum for these types of questions.  I don't have a recommendation for a more relevant forum.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are sometimes good reasons for having multiple concurrent queues. It's more common with serial queues, but there are situations where multiple concurrent queues can be useful.

You might have sets of tasks that you want to run at different priorities, for example.